# Angular ng-bind disappearing using escaped fragments with Mean-SEO

Tags: angularjs, meanjs

I have an angular web app that I am trying to get escaped_fragments to work using Mean-seo  (under the covers it uses phantomjs headless browser)

I am getting strange behaviour I can't explain. 
The non escaped fragment works fine.
With escaped fragments some of the content immediately disappears.

I have an object that I am reading from the mongo db in the resolve section of the routes config like so.

```
state('view-creator-test', {
            url: '/view-creator-test/:creatorId',
            templateUrl: 'modules/creators/views/view-creator-test.client.view.html',
            resolve: {
                creator: function($stateParams, Creators) {
                    return Creators.get({
                        creatorId: $stateParams.creatorId
                    }).$promise;
                }
            },
            controller: function($scope, creator) {
                $scope.resolveCreator = creator;
            }
        }).
```

then the view template is

```
<section data-ng-controller="CreatorTestController"  >
      <!-- !CREATOR PROFILE -->
  <section class="profile-header inverse">
    <div class="container">
      <!-- AVATAR -->
      <div class="row">

        <!-- NAME / LOCATION -->
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-12 text-center-sm">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
              <h2 class="name">{{creator.name}}</h2>
              <h2 class="name" ng-bind="creator.name"></h2>
            </div>
              <h2 class="name">{{test}}</h2>
              <h2 class="name" ng-bind="test"></h2>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</section>
```

then the controller is

```
'use strict';

angular.module('creators').controller('CreatorTestController', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
        $scope.test = 'Leo was Here';
        $scope.creator = $scope.resolveCreator;
  }]);
```

the result is that the creator name is filled in for {{creator.name}} but is not filled in for ng-bind="creator.name".
'Leo was here' is filled in for both.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of defining `controller` function in state and then do assign that `$scope` inside variable through template, you could place the `CreatorTestController` inside the route, so that you directly inject the dependency inside the `CreatorTestController` function, Remove `ng-controller` from the template

```
   .state('view-creator-test', {
        url: '/view-creator-test/:creatorId',
        templateUrl: 'modules/creators/views/view-creator-test.client.view.html',
        resolve: {
            creator: function($stateParams, Creators) {
                return Creators.get({
                    creatorId: $stateParams.creatorId
                }).$promise;
            }
        },
        controller: 'CreatorTestController'
    })
```

**Controller**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('creators').controller('CreatorTestController', ['$scope', 'creator', //<-- injected resolve method here.
    function($scope, creator) {
        $scope.test = 'Leo was Here';
        $scope.creator = creator;
}]);
```

Comment: This still has same error the ngBind is empty and the {{}} is working but interestingly enough now I get the problem with both test and creator where as before I was only getting the error with creator. both of these work except when using escaped_fragments